# How do I find out the cursor_id for kill_cursors()?

Tags: python, mongodb, cursor, pymongo

The PyMongo API documentation mentions a function to kill a mongodb cursor:

```
kill_cursors(cursor_ids) Send a kill cursors message with the given ids.
Raises TypeError if cursor_ids is not an instance of list.
Parameters :     cursor_ids: list of cursor ids to kill
```

However, it doesn't specify (as far as I can see) how to actually find out the id of your cursor. How can I get this?

```
from pymongo import Connection
c = Connection()
crawl = c.db.coll.find()
print crawl.id? <-- no idea how to get this
```

Comment: once the cursor is executed it's in cursor._Cursor__id (which will be set to 0 before the cursor is executed)

Answer (score 0):

There's never a need for you to explicitly kill a cursor. The server cleans up cursors automatically once you've retrieved all the results from a cursor. (e.g., with a `for doc in collection.find()` loop.) If you don't retrieve all results, PyMongo kills the cursor automatically when its Cursor instance is dereferenced. So for example:

`for doc in collection.find():
    assert False  # raise exception`

When the cursor goes out of scope, PyMongo automatically calls kill_cursors to clean up the cursor server-side.

Answer (score -1):

Jesse, I may still want to kill a cursor explicitly if I find out it's a rogue cursor, or during testing. Having that option in the java script admin console will be a plus. In addition to that, do we have a way to list all the open cursors on a mongo server?

Comment: Yes. It's a followup question. Do we have a way to print all the open cursor IDs in mongo?